# Salesforce Formula Text Value Based on Custom Field Picklist Value

Tags: salesforce

I am getting to the point where Salesforce is becoming a pain. The limitations are astounding.

Basically, on Cases, I have:

Department(picklist values=Ecom, B2B, etc.)
Manager(text field)
Employee 1(text field)
Employee 2(text field)
Employee 3(text field)
Employee 4(text field)

This is what I am trying to do in real time, not on save (workflow rule won't work because it only does field updates after creating the ticket, not during the creation of it):
IF(ISPICKVAL(Department__c, "Ecom"),Employee_1__c="John Smith", Employee_2__c="Jane Doe", etc.)

It keeps telling me I can't use a formula on the picklist field so then I tried to do it on each of the employee fields but they are not formula and only text fields.

I created another field that is Formula(text) and put in a formula:

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Department__c,"Ecom"),"test",null)
```

This works but only for the formula(text) field, if I try to have it update the other text fields, it also does not allow me to do this and gives a boolean error, tried replacing null with "false" "true" with no difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would update the fields using the field update features that the platform offers. You can then use a formula like IF xxxx THEN do this and this and this field update.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_managing_field_updates.htm&type=0

Comment: Hello, thank you for this information. Unfortunately, I was unable to get salesforce to update the fields in real time rather than having it update the fields after "Save". I ended up using web-to-case and creating an html page within salesforce and using jquery to auto-populate fields based on a selection which would then update the fields technically in real time into salesforce. Thanks again for your response.